# Retreive all github repositories include in array of repositories Id

Tags: javascript, github-api

There are any way to get all repositories included in array of repositories ids?

Something like this ...

```
const githubRepoIds = [ 1,2,3 ];
fetch(`/search/repositories/q=${githubRepoIds.join(',')} in:id`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof-of-concept that makes 1 request per repository id (see [rate limiting](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)).

```
function getRepositories(ids) {
    var promises = ids.map(id => getRepository(id).catch(() => {}));
    return Promise.all(promises).then(repos => repos.filter(repo => repo !== undefined));

    function getRepository(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = "https://api.github.com/repositories/" + id;
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    } else {
                        reject();
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const githubRepoIds = [ 1,2,3 ];
getRepositories(githubRepoIds).then(repos => console.log(repos));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `in` qualifier does allow you only to limit search to repository name, description, readme and combination of those. Please see: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#scope-the-search-fields